# need help for solving circular dependency

Tags: powerbi, dax, circular-dependency

I need to calculate a column with an IF() function based on two tables, but I receive a circular dependency error.

have the data model as shown in the image below.

I have two columns called A and B in my fact table, and a column named "employed more than 3 months" in my employee dimension table. (please ignore the other columns)

What I need is to have a column as following in my fact table:

```
C= A- B
```

and then I need to have a column which produce the result as follow:

```
result= IF [C <= 0 AND [employyed more than 3 months] = 'True'
THEN [C]
ELSE 0
END
```

I tried to create a calculated column with CALCULATE() function, but I receive a circular dependency error.

can someone help me create this?[image]

Comment: Looks like you are using A or B in your [employyed more than 3 months] calculation. Could you please confirm?

Comment: "I tried to create a calculated column with CALCULATE() function" - please post your code that generated the error.

Comment: @Mboolean, [employed more than 3 months] is just a column from the table which says whether the person is employed more than three months or not. No calculation is used for this column.

Comment: Try something like                                                                                
Calculated Column = 

VAR CALC = CALCULATE (A-B,[Employyed more than 3 Months] = "True")

RETURN

IF(ISBLANK(CALC),0, CALC)